# python: search for a string in text file ; extract its timestamp ; store string and timestamp in dictionary

Tags: python

```
d = {}

with open('C:/log') as f: 
    lines = f.read().splitlines() 
for line in lines: 

    if 'string_1' in line: 
        time = line[0:21] 
        d['string_1'] = time 

    elif 'string_2' in line: 
        time = line[0:21] 
        d['string_2'] = time 

    elif 'string_3' in line: 
        time = line[0:21] 
        d['string_3'] = time 
print(d)
```

ex of text big file lines

```
[20:25:48.923 -06:00] [thread 19] [Mobility.cpp] [string_1].......
```

output

```
{'stirng_1': '[20:25:48.923 -06:00]', 'string_2': '[20:89:48.275 -06:00]'}
```

I have a big text file. I need to search for multiple strings in the file ,extract their timestamp [20:89:48.275 -06:00] and store in a dictionary. Not all lines have strings only a few lines have the required string in the file. key being string and value being timestamp. I have the code above, how do I make it more efficient?. Mainly how to extract timestamp in a better way? beginner here

Comment: You could use a regular expression that matches any of the strings. But the bottleneck is reading the file, there's not much you can do to improve that.

Comment: Unless the lines are very long, the performance of `string in line` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't think you can extract the timestamp in any better way. String slicing is a very simple operation.

Comment: @Barmar ended up modifying to this d['string1'].append(time) , Thank you

Comment: That's a separate issue from how you extract the time from the line.